# Please help? question about fasting

Tags: ramadan

I accidentally flirted and sexted while fasting, does this mean it is invalid and I have to make it up? Please let me know as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: And why do you think your fasting would be invalid?

Comment: Because i heard doing anything sexual can break your fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you masturbated when sexting, yes. But if not, repent because as Muslims, we shouldn't have these thoughts, specifically when fasting. Instead, fill your mind with Quran.

Answer (score 0):

It will reduce the barakah but it won't break the fast. Physical sexual activity is the one that will break the fast. Either you had intercourse or you had manual ejaculation then your fast is broken.

Answer (score -2):

your fast is invalid. i think you have fast for 60 days now. i am not scholar though. talking out of memory. if you intentionally flirted, knowing it is ramadan, and had a sex knowing it is ramadan. i think you should fast for 60 days if you break your fast intentionally. and make up days if you were sick for some days or had a menstrual cicle.

Comment: He didn't had sex, he only did talking as per the question.